# Saving .R script File Using Script

Tags: r, rstudio

I am using R Studio and I want to save my script (i.e., the upper left panel). However, the only ways that I can find to do it are by either clicking the blue floppy disk icon to save or using the drop down menu File > Save > name.R

Is there any way besides using these shortcuts to save the script to a .R file or is the shortcut the only way?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are on Windows, the classic Ctrl + S

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That suggestion is useful to quickly save, but I was hoping to be able to add in some script that would enable me to save an .R file. I'd really like to build in the save command to my script if possible.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to save a previously unsaved script (e.g. "Untitled" tab) or are you trying to save a script that already exists on disk?

Comment: I'm trying accomplish both--saving a previously untitled script and trying to save over an existing script

Comment: I'm looking for the very same thing to run a script which saves the (unsaved) .R file... Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rstudioapi::documentSave()` to save the currently open script file to disk.

From the source documentation, one can see that it can be used in conjunction with the id returned with `getActiveDocumentContext()$id` to make sure the document saved is the one running the script.

For your intended use, try:

```
rstudioapi::documentSave(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$id)
```

For future reference, here is the reference manual of rstudioapi:
https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/rstudioapi/rstudioapi.pdf

Comment: I get the result `TRUE`, but the current new file doesn't save. Do you know how to actually  save the file? My file is `.Rmd`

Comment: That's an R markdown document, not an R script file. I don't know how that would work. EDIT: When you knit the markdown document it should be saved automatically. I think that and Ctrl+S are your only solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet allowed to comment, but this refers to the comment above that this does not work with .rmd files:

```
rstudioapi::documentSave(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$id)
```

I tried and in Rstudio Version 1.2.5042 it does seem to work.

Comment: Heads up, if you include this at the top RMarkdown notebooks, it will not knit properly and throw an error.

Answer (score -1):

Every new tab in R(created by ctrl+shift+n) can be independently saved by using ctrl+s in the respective tab. If you intend to rename the file though, you may do it as you would rename any file in windows(goto the file location and single click on the filename). Hope my answer was of some help!

Comment: Hi, should you read first [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)