# How to Auto-Create/Save .rmd File

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R-Studio it is fairly easy to create folders and other elements in any directory. But if I wanted to save the R-Markdown file itself, with the name "Template" in the directory, how would I do that?

I am not interested in clkicking "File > Save" I want the code to auto-save the file in the directory.

```
Creating a folder getwd() #Get Working Directory
setwd("~/Desktop") #Set Working Directory
dir.create("Template") #Create New Folder
setwd("~/Desktop/Template") #Get New Folder as Working Directory

# Create Sub-Directory
dir.create("Results")
dir.create("Code")
dir.create("Data")
```

The above code would create a series of folders. But now I want to save this R-Markdown in the folder "Template" with the name "template.rmd".

Thanks.

Comment: This [solution][1] in an older thread should work.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62594975/16745699

Comment: That solution works for R script files, not .rmd R Markdown files @SpikyClip

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can read the file with readLines and then save it using write.

(since you
`setwd("~/Desktop/Template")`
use `../` to read from parent directory )

```
self<-readLines("../test.Rmd")
write(self,file = "template.rmd")
```

where test.Rmd is the file you want to copy

Answer (score 0):

This has become pretty common in my workflow. Here is my current method:

````css
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Load the wbstats package
packages <- c("wbstats", "dplyr", "tidyverse", 
              "openxlsx", "rstudioapi", "wbstats",
              "scales", "ggplot2")
for (pkg in packages) {
  if (!require(pkg, character.only = TRUE)) {
    install.packages(pkg, dependencies = TRUE)
    library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, quietly = TRUE)
  }
}
# Clear workspace
rm(list = ls())
setwd("~/Desktop")
cat("\014")  # Sends a form feed character which clears the console
```

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
# Define base and subdirectories
base_directory <- "~/Desktop/Distribution"
sub_directories <- c("Results", "Code", "Data")
# Extract current filename
filename <- gsub(".*/", "", documentPath()) 
# Delete old work and create base directory
unlink(base_directory, recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(base_directory)
# Create subdirectories
for (sub_dir in sub_directories) {
    dir.create(file.path(base_directory, sub_dir))}
# Move and rename file to Code directory
file_path <- file.path(base_directory, "Code", filename)
file.copy(from = filename, to = file_path)
file.rename(from = file_path, to = file.path(base_directory, "Code", "code.Rmd"))
# Set working directory
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = "/Users/marksheppard/Desktop/Distribution") #Change accordingly
# Clear console again
cat("\014")
```
````